# New row disappearing after getting added to html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to add a new row dynamically to my HTML. 
When I enter the details and hit submit, the new row shows up momentarily and disappears. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
function addNewRow(){
    var tab = document.getElementById("table"),
        newRow = tab.insertRow(table.length),
        cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
        cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
        cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
        cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3),
        cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4),
        date = document.getElementById("date-input").value,
        time = document.getElementById("time-input").value,
        amount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value,
        source = document.getElementById("source-input").value,
        destination = document.getElementById("dest-input").value;

        cell1.innerHTML = date;
        cell2.innerHTML = time;
        cell3.innerHTML = amount;
        cell4.innerHTML = source;
        cell5.innerHTML = destination;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    addNewRow();
})
```

Comment: By "submit" are you submitting a form?

Comment: Yes, I am using a form. I removed the form, but now the data is not showing up in the table. The code just adds a new table row with no data..

Comment: Sorry, it's because of typos in my code. Removing form tag solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You could also change the button type from submit to button (: